# Find Radius between two different lat lng?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have lat lng in db column named as lat_lng = 31.16680769816029,72.67189561178552.
Now I pass a different lat_lng, need to find the difference(Radius) between that two Lat_longs in laravel eloquent?

Comment: Eloquent isn't the best way to handle it.  Do the calculation outside of the eloquent command, or if you really want it calculated in the db use raw sql in it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have used to store your latitude and longitude as a one string is very poor. Normally, you would just make calculations based on two fields `lat` and `lng`, and your basics of mathematics (Pythagorean theorem).

When you use string however, you first need to get the string, than split it, convert to numbers and only than you are able to make calculations. Pretty bad on performance, right?

---

When you decide to use eg. `DOUBLE(16,14)` as your field type in SQL, things are really easy.

You make a statement like

```
SQRT ( ( lat - x ) * ( lat - x ) + ( lng - x ) * ( lng - x ) )
```

and it easily gives you the range.